# Rails 5: PUT doesn't work using friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok... so now I'm at day 2 trying to figure out why on my **development** env, it works but when I deploy my app to **production** it doesn't work.

I'm simply trying to create a "like/upvote" button and count the "likes/upvotes" on every post, and then do the same for every comment in a post.

Since I'm using **friendly_id** to create a slug from the :title field, I'm getting this in my **Heroku** Logs:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/posts/test/upvote"):

I obviously get the "This page doesn't exist" error...

Here's the code:

> routes.rb

```
  resources :posts, only: [:create, :index, :show, :destroy, :edit, :update] do
    resources :comments, only: [:show, :create, :destroy, :edit, :update] do
      member do
        put '/upvote' => 'comments#upvote'
      end
    end

    member do
      put '/upvote' => 'posts#upvote'
    end
  end
end
```

> post_controller.rb

```
  def upvote
   @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @post.increment!(:upvotes)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

> comments_controller.rb

```
  def upvote
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.increment!(:upvotes)
    redirect_to @post
  end
```

> post index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "like", upvote_post_path(post), method: :put, style: "color: white;" %>
```

What's missing here that I'm not seeing?

Comment: `put :upvote` is sufficient. You don't need to specify the path as a string and rails will assign the route to `comments#upvote` by convention.

Comment: Also you might want to read up on shallow nesting - there is no reason for the routes to like or dislike a comment to be nested under post.

Comment: yeah, that didn't work, but thank you for the heads up on shallow nesting..

Comment: your log is saying no route error on `GET "/posts/test/upvote"`, but your routes.rb is defined to work for `PUT "/posts/test/upvote"` instead. Which means that your `<%= link_to ... method: :put %> didn't send a PUT request but instead a GET request, which most likely that the link might not have been rendered correctly (it should be something like <a href="..." data-method="put">, or that you haven't included jquery_ujs properly in the production, or perhaps it is not loaded (check for 404s in any of your asset files being fetched from your browser in production)

Comment: It's definitely a jquery-ujs issue, the `link_to` is correct.

Comment: It works perfectly in my dev environment. Maybe an issue with heroku and it's asset pipeline?

Comment: That's a definite symptom of assets precompilation failing or including assets the wrong way. How are you including them and precompiling before deploying?

Comment: Hello everyone, my "like" button in the app says <a hred="/post/test/upvote" data-method="put"> as it should. I'm following the Rails 4+ Asset Pipeline from Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline. But still haven't figured out why....